# Conditional move based on uninitialized values, Uninitalized values was created by heap allocation

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

Hi I am getting the the following error from valgrind.

> Conditional move based on uninitialized values, Uninitalized values was created by heap allocation.

The compiler does not complain.

I looked at most of the similar errors at stackoverflow, but I can't seem to pinpoint what's wrong with mine.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int
    main(void)
     {

      char *string1 = malloc(45);
      char string2[25] = "HELLO WORLD";
      strcpy(string1,string2);
      printf("String one is %s\n",string1);

      char string3[25];
      for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
       {
        string3[i] = tolower(string1[i]);

       }
      printf("The output is %s\n",string3);
      free(string1);
      return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Was there any more line information? Can you try running it with `--track-origins=yes`? That may help you pinpoint the problem, though in this example you only make one heap allocation, so it's probably `string1`.

Comment: @DanFego, Yes, I am running it with --track-origins=yes. Without the track command it shows conditional jump based on uninitialized values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping from 0 to 24 along `string1`, which has only been initialized `strlen("HELLO WORLD") + 1` bytes. Bytes indexed from 12 to 24 there have not been initialized, and you shouldn't be trying to read them. You should either use `calloc()` to allocate `string1` or use `memset()` to initialize it, like so:

```
char *string1 = calloc(1, 45);
```

or

```
char *string1 = malloc(45);
memset(string1, 0, 45);
```

Or you could initialize `string3` to zeroes with the above methods and then only copy `strlen(string1)` bytes.

Comment: Thanks I will try using calloc and memset.

Comment: @kevin, for clarity, you _probably_ just want to do the `calloc()` version. I just left in the `malloc()`/`memset()` bit to show what you were trying to accomplish with initialization. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your `tolower` call accesses the first 25 bytes of the memory pointed to by `string1`, but only the first *twelve* bytes of that memory are in a valid state (thanks to the `strcpy`).

You could use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to allocate memory with a deterministic state. Alternatively, only copy as many bytes as you need:

```
{
    const unsigned int M = max(24, strlen(string1));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != M; ++i)
        string3[i] = tolower(string1[i]);
    string3[M] = 0;
}
```

Comment: yes removing the tolower() makes it go away. But is there any other way around, without removing it?

Comment: @kevin: You should probably make the loop only go up to `max(24, strlen(string1))`, and then don't forget to set the last one to zero. I added the code.

Comment: @kevin: Just as a note, I'd probably prefer the restricted loop over `calloc`, simply because what you *want* is to transform the string, not populate 25 bytes of memory. There's no reason you *should* be forced into the pointless initialization of memory you never use, and restricting the loop is more "deliberate".

Comment: I think so too. But given a choice between saving space and a fast running time, which one would you choose? A note aside, This logic is part of another program(to implement a fast spellchecker). I isolated this piece of code to find the error from valgrind.

Comment: Well, `calloc`+25 zeroes out all the bytes and then proceeds to copy all 25 bytes, while `malloc`+`M` doesn't do any initialization and copies *at most* 25 bytes, but usually fewer... take a guess ;-) "Saving space" doesn't come in to this, as you always allocate 25 bytes. You just don't always *use* all of them.